# GA Cross Domain Tracking - Not Tracking Correctly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, cross-domain, universal-analytics

Really hope you can help. I'm setting up cross domain tracking for a site that has it's checkout process on a separate domain.

I set up a brand new **Universal Analytics** account to track both sites, and initially had implemented the wrong (classic analytics) cross domain code on site 1...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'site1.co.uk']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';
  ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 
  'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

However this was tracking correctly in the new UA account. As soon as I noticed I had the old version on the code on there I changed it to..

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||
[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,'script','//www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', ‘site1.co.uk' ‘auto’, {
  ‘allowLinker’: true
});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['site2.co.uk'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

But now tracking has messed up and it's gone from tracking thousands of visits a day to under 100. Is there something wrong with the new code I put on here? Seems weird to be tracking fine with the old GA code and not the new.

I haven't put the code on site 2 yet, want to get this right first. Would appreciate any help here, and bear in mind I'm no coder :)

Thanks so much, 
David

Comment: So I just noticed that the old (wrong) code that was put on the site is still on a few stray pages and these are now the only ones that are tracking.

Is this somehow overwriting the new code on the other pages?

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` on your script tags?

Comment: As far as I'm aware this isn't needed for Universal Analytics script tags?

Comment: Ah. Looking at googles own code. that isn't the problem, but I know what is...

Comment: What's that then? Is it simply that some pages have classic code and some have universal, so Google is only tracking the classic code?

Comment: Sorry was writing an answer, should have explained that's what I was up to.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', ‘site1.co.uk' ‘auto’, { ‘allowLinker’: true    });
```

From the the reference ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/method-reference#create ):

```
ga('create', trackingId, opt_configObject);
```

You can't drop the domain into the create statement for the tracker. Even if you could, you missed a comma and used backticks rather than single quotes.  Moreover, the domainName is no longer an exposed option like it used to be.  If you want one code to track the two domains your best bet now is to put the domain in a custom variable, userDefined value or custom dimension.

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'site1.co.uk');
```

**Edit:**

Looking through the documentation there is a hostname field that can be set:

```
ga('set', 'hostname', 'site1.co.uk');
```

Moreover, and I didn't think to ask this before, but you did upgrade the UA account to Google Analytics Universal right?  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3450662?hl=en

Comment: I got the code directly from google -https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en-GB

So am I to disregard this?

Comment: If it isn't working, and it contradicts the reference doc, I would at least try it another way.  That said, I've edited my answer to include two more ideas.  There is a hostname field you can set, and none of that matters if you haven't upgraded the UA code to universal in the Google Analyics web interface.